# How to use FaceID for facial movement recognition?

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

Is it possibile to use FaceID to recognise facial movements, such as left-to-right or viceversa? I've looked in documentation but haven't found what I was looking for.

Comment: `FaceID` is the technology to recognise a user face, which is handled by the iOS. `FaceID` is not a camera technologie.

Comment: How do you suggest me to implement that function (recognise a facial movement)?